# If statement with || and multiple &&

Tags: java, if-statement

I have booleans A, B, C, D set to false.

I have following code `if (A && B || C && D) {Debug.i("Check", "stars")}`

When will I get `"stars"` message?

1. When **A** and **B**  **OR** **C** and **D** set to true.
2. When **A**, **B**/**C**, **D** set to true

=============================

**ANSWER**

A && B || C && D

should be treated as

(A && B) || (C && D)

Comment: I get the edit. But why all the vote downs?

Comment: You can easily debug this yourself.... or write tests....etc.
See this...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction

Comment: If you hover over the downvote button, you'll notice _This question does not show any research effort, it is not clear or not useful._

Comment: I believe people are down voting because it is encouraged to add a question only when stuck. Have you tried any debugging or printing yourself?

Comment: My initial question was a bit more complicated, and I spent quite some time stripping it 'till the very core was left.. Now that I think about it.... Damn XD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boolean order of operations is the following:

1. Parentheses
2. NOT
3. AND
4. OR

So you are right in your examples.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the "stars" message when both A and B are set to true OR C and D are set to true.